# how to switch a magento store/installation from a domain to an IP address

Tags: magento-1.7

I am trying to move and setup a magento based shop, its currently installed on this domain http://www.smokewire.com to a new server. My client wants to use the new server as a dev server for development of new new extensions for testing purpose, for upgrades etc. He wants to keep the dev server just on a IP address. This is the server ip to where I moved all files and created/restored the DB: 94.75.216.74 (responds quite slowly).  You can see the error:There has been an error processing your request Illegal scheme supplied, only alphanumeric characters are permitted

After DB was restored I simple updated core_config_data table and changed values in web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url from http://www.smokewire.com to 94.75.216.74, I thought thats the only thing I had to do?

But it doesn't look like that :( I already tried few things that I found online: manual cache cleaning in /var/cache folder, changing file permission for public_html to 0777 and changing file and group owner to glass pipes (account owner) since they were owned by apache. Still I have the same error?

Comment: The error says you're using an invalid **scheme**. Did you already double check, that your `base_url`s start with either `http://` or `https://`?

Comment: web/unsecure/base_url is set to: http://94.75.216.74/

Comment: web/secure/base_url set to: http://94.75.216.74/

Comment: with http and https in front and / at the end

Answer (score 1):

You could always use a subdomain like development.smokewire.com. Set up the subdomain on your DNS management service and point it to 94.75.216.74. Then you can set up a Named Virtual Host on your new box with that domain to serve your Magento install, and use that domain in your Magento config.

If you want to disallow indexing, create a robots.txt in the root or edit the head.phtml file of your theme to add the appropriate meta.

To disallow regular user access, you can either set up HTTP Basic authentication for the site on the dev box, or if you have mod rewrite you can set up a default page for all users by redirecting to that page if not visiting from specific IPs.

**EDIT**: Also I forgot to mention, if the development box doesn't have SSL enabled, use http and not https on the secure URL as well as the unsecure URL.

Comment: Sorry but I am not the owner of the business. My client said he wants a copy of his online store on this new server for development purpose and for a clear backup. It makes sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it depends on the number of stores in your shop

If you have one store you can simply edit your app/etc/local.xml

```
<config>
    <stores>
        <default>
            <web>
                <unsecure>
                    <base_url><![CDATA[http://94.75.216.74/]]></base_url>
                </unsecure>
                <secure>
                    <base_url><![CDATA[http://94.75.216.74/]]></base_url>
                </secure>
            </web>
        </default>
        <admin>
            <web>
                <unsecure>
                    <base_url><![CDATA[http://94.75.216.74/]]></base_url>
                </unsecure>
                <secure>
                    <base_url><![CDATA[http://94.75.216.74/]]></base_url>
                </secure>
            </web>
        </admin>
    </stores>
</config>
```

If you have multistore you need to create module that changes base_url to 94.75.216.74

something like

```
$config = Mage::getConfig();
$config->setNode("stores/$code/web/unsecure/base_url", 'http://94.75.216.74/');
$config->setNode("stores/$code/web/secure/base_url", 'http://94.75.216.74/');
```